# How can i go to a branch of my college working with fork?

Tags: git, github

All of my team are working in his own fork, now i have to go the  branch (of my college), i tried to go but there is not in the list of the branch in my terminal

i made these steps:

`git fetch` to get latest list of branches.

`git checkout theBranch` //go in to the branch

but doesnot worked for me, do you know how can i solve this?

this is the error:

```
git fetch origin RT204               
fatal: couldn't find remote ref RT204
```

the RT204 is in review PR to merge to original project

Comment: Are they really using a separate fork (which would be a separate git repository based on the original) or just a branch on the shared central repository? What hosting software do you use? (GitHub? GitLab? Bitbucket? Something else?) Did your colleague push their branch (i.e. upload it)? Also: whenever you say "does not work" in a question that means you must explain what exactly happened: what error message did you get or how did the behaviour deviate from what you wanted?

Comment: Each fork is a *separate repository* and will therefore have separate branches. Your fork won't have their branch, and their fork won't have your branch.

Comment: @letters: if they are actually using a real fork, then just fetching won't give you their work, you'll need to add a separate remote for that fork and fetch from that.

Comment: You use `github`, is that correct ?

Comment: @LeGEC yes of course

Comment: there is a ref that points at the commit of a pull request, but it is not a standard branch : run `git fetch origin refs/pull/<PR id>/head`, this should get you a commit. You can then inspect it however you like.

Comment: the name of that ref depends on the kind of server (that's why I was asking "is it github ?"), but you can actually see how these refs are organizaed by running `git ls-remote` (<- this will show you the refs you can get for any kind of remote).

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions (some of which are in your question, some are from comments):

- You all use GitHub.
- There's a single "original" repository *on* GitHub, that each of your fork on GitHub, using the <kbd>FORK THIS REPOSITORY</kbd> button on GitHub.
- You also use a *clone* of your fork on your laptop.

Given the above, you have, on your laptop, a Git repository that you made by running `git clone ssh-or-https-url`, with the URL being the one GitHub provided you *after* you made a fork.  So on your laptop, if you run `git remote -v`, you will see one identical pair of URLs listed under the name `origin`, e.g.:

```
origin  ssh://git@github.com/someone/repo.git (fetch)
origin  ssh://git@github.com/someone/repo.git (push)
```

If all of the above is correct, you now must *add* **at least** one more remote.

#### What a remote is, and how to add one

A Git *remote* is mostly just a short name for a URL.  This short name exists in your *laptop* clone.  It does not exist *on GitHub* anywhere.  You already have one, namely `origin`, and it stands for the URL you saw when you ran `git remote -v`.

You must pick a second short name.  This name is up to you.  It's somewhat standard for people to use `upstream` as the second remote name.  *I personally don't like this name so I recommend making up a different one, but the actual string is not that important here.*  For the rest of this answer, I'm going to use the short string `corprepo` instead (for "corporate repository").  This is a clumsy name but avoids the issue with the word *upstream*.<sup>1</sup>

To add a remote, use `git remote add remote url`.  Since we'll be using `corprepo`, that becomes `git remote add corprepo url`.  The URL you need here is the URL GitHub will give you for the repository you forked, e.g., `ssh://git@github.com/corp-account/repo.git`, so you might run:

```
git remote add corprepo ssh://git@github.com/corp-account/repo.git
```

Make any appropriate changes required (to the URL, and perhaps to the upstream name if you don't like `corprepo`) and run this command, then make sure you can *retrieve stuff from* the corporate repository.

You may also, if you like or prefer, add a *third* upstream, or add as your second upstream your co-worker's repository, provided you have access *to* this co-worker's repository.  For instance, you might run:

```
git remote add fred ssh://git@github.com/fred/repo.git
```

(make any appropriate substitutions here).

Verify that you can `git fetch` from your various upstreams:

```
git fetch corprepo
```

and/or:

```
git fetch fred
```

If you got the URL wrong, you can remove and re-add the remote, or run `git config --edit` to open `.git/config` in your preferred editor so that you can edit the URL.

---

<sup>1</sup>The issue with the word *upstream* here is that each branch can have one (1) *upstream* setting.  This upstream setting is *not related to* a remote named `upstream`.  When you have no remote named `upstream`, it's clear that there's no relationship between "the upstream of branch X" and "the remote named `upstream`" since there is no remote named `upstream` in the first place.

---

#### Once you have your remote(s) added, you must use them

To obtain the commits that your co-worker Fred (or whoever) sent to the corporate repository as GitHub Pull Request #123, you now need a rather peculiar `git fetch` command:

```
git fetch corprepo refs/pull/123/head:refs/heads/pr123
```

This `git fetch` command will obtain the pull request commits from the corporate repository and create a new branch name in your own repository, `pr123`.  That allows you to see the commits on your laptop, because those commits *are* now on your laptop.

To obtain the commits from Fred's repository, simply run:

```
git fetch fred
```

This `git fetch` command will obtain *all* of Fred's GitHub-repository commits and branch names, so if Fred *made* Pull Request #123 from Fred's branch that Fred named "fix-broken-thing", you now have `refs/remotes/fred/fix-broken-thing` as a *remote-tracking name* in your own repository.  A remote-tracking name is a lot like a branch name, except that it's not *your* branch, it's your own Git software's way of *remembering* someone *else's* branch name.

You can now view these commits under the name `fred/fix-broken-thing`.  Or, if you like, you can create your own branch name.  For instance, if you wanted to call this `pr123` (a branch) you would run:

```
git branch pr123 fred/fix-broken-thing
```

and you can now proceed in the same way that you would had you used `git fetch corprepo refs/pull/123/head:refs/heads/pr123`.

#### The `gh` CLI

If you're going to do this sort of thing a lot, you may find that GitHub's [command-line `gh` command](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh) is useful to you.  I have not actually used `gh` and have no particular recommendation one way or another here.  The rest of this answer is pure Git and is how I used to do this, when I had to do this.